# Connecting two computers using socket programming in scala

Tags: scala, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I'm trying to connect my laptop to another laptop in another network and I did the following:

1- Make the two ports are opened in both my friend's laptop and mine     manually

2-The firewall is off in both laptops also

Below is my code

Server class :

```
// Simple server
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._

object Server {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val server = new ServerSocket(2076)
    while (true) {
      val s = server.accept()
      val in = new BufferedSource(s.getInputStream()).getLines()
      val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream())
      out.println(in.next())
      out.flush()
      s.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Client class :

```
// Simple client
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.io._

object Client {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

//  val s = new Socket("192.168.1.15",2076)
    val s = new Socket("185.98.222.147",2076)
    lazy val in = new BufferedSource(s.getInputStream()).getLines()
    val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream())
    out.println("Hello, world")
    out.flush()
    println("Received: " + in.next())
    s.close()
  }
}
```

I tried to run the code two times:
first with my friend's local IP and I got this error below,and when I tried my friend's public IP the code didn't do anything just waiting in both sides.
Can anyone please tell me what we are doing wrong?

```
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at Client$.main(Client.scala:9)
        at Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:34)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:30)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:91)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:66)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:85)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:101)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: Can you please print `server.getLocalSocketAddress` and see what the ip address the server binds too?

Comment: I got this :  0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:11164

Comment: This is strange, as it's not port 2076, specified in your server. Can you connect to the printed port from Client?

Comment: Sorry I tried another port, I forgot that the port in the question was 2076 , even though it will give me the same  0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2076